# Loop Multiple Audio Tracks (Sound Mixer) Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am trying to create an audio Mixer application in Flash using Action Script 3.
The application has 9 buttons when a button is clicked a sound will loop, from an external mp3.
I can get the sound to play (not looped) when the button is clicked, but cannot figure out how to allow multiple sounds to be played at once, when more than one buttons is clicked.

Here is my code to play the sound:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Sound/Melody1.mp3");

var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var controller:SoundChannel;

function soundLoaded(event:Event):void

{

controller = sound.play();

controller.stop();

Btn_Melody1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

}

function playSound(event:MouseEvent):void

{

controller = sound.play();

}

sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);

sound.load(req);
```

.

This is the first stage, next I am going to try and add a volume slider, mute, reset.

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since both your sounds are loaded with the same variable, they cannot be played together. Use different instance variables to hold different sounds.
For more help visit http://www.kennybellew.com/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Inquizitive, they are really good tutorials.
I have been able to make all nine buttons loop sounds, and reset (stop) them as well as mute them all, and change the volume.
The only thing I am having trouble with is the play back of the sounds, there seems to be a gap in the loop.
I am using an external mp3 file, and have edited it in audacity t ensure there is no gap in the file.
Here is my code for the loop:
var s3:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Sound/Melody3.mp3"));
fl_SC3 = s3.play(0,999);